# Get absolute coordinates of an Item in GridView Android

Tags: android, gridview, position, coordinate

I want to get absolute coordinates (X, Y) of an item in a GridView.

I have position of this item in the GridView.

How can I get X, Y of this Item on the screen?

I wish there was `positionToPoint` instead of `pointToPosition`!

Comment: Do you mean the coordinate of which cell the item is in the grid? Or do you want the absolute coordinate on the screen? Or the absolute coordinate relative to the gridView?

Comment: Can you make your question more clear ?

Comment: I wanna absolute coordinate on the screen for item at position `"n" `in the gridview.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i understand your question ,you can use pointToPosition method , available in [GridView Android API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html)

```
if (myGridView.pointToPosition((int)e.getX(), (int)e.getY())!=-1) {
 myItem = myGridViewAdapter.getItem(myGridView.pointToPosition((int)e.getX(), (int)e.getY()));
}
```

Comment: No this is not my answer! I need something like `positionToPoint` not `pointToPosition`!!!

Comment: @Jessica You want to move the gridview item to a particular point or coordinates ? 
Or is just want to find the coordinate of the item you do an touch event on ?

Comment: I just want to find the coordinate of any item in Gridview not just item that is touched.

Comment: did you get the position of grid view item xy co ordinates?